# Creating many small forms as a substitute for message box or input box

Tags: vb.net, forms, messagebox, inputbox

Am I practicing a good coding standard in .NET if I will create so many small forms that acts like a customize message box or input box?

I think that it will be hard to maintain it if I do it like that, but there isn't any way to customize a message box or input box freely.

This is an input box

[image]

And this is the form that I am using, just like a modified input box / message box

[image]

I also think that it is much better if I will not create a form just for that purpose, but I don't have a way to fully customize the message box or input box to make it like that. On the other hand, I am concern that if I create more than 10 of that small form if might be hard for me to maintain it in the future.

Comment: Do you just need a name for `Add Teller` ??

Comment: @Vivek.S, I am also a little bit confuse about my question before so I revised it. Take a look and let me know if I can still do something with it.

Comment: What's your question ? What you're trying to achieve? This questions seems unclear for me. OTOH If I understood correctly you can go for [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

Comment: @Vivek.S I just checked the User Control and it looks promising, is it possible to put different user control in 1 form depending on the situation? For example if I click the btn_add it will show user_control_add in form1, then when I click btn_edit it will show user_control_edit in form1?

Comment: @CaryBondoc yes you can decide at runtime which usercontrol you'd like to use based on your conditions at the time.

Comment: @Mort that's my question I just don't know how to say it like that. :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a short example showing how you can add a UserControl at run-time.
AddCtrl is your add UserControl. UpdateCtrl is your editing UserControl.
You would still need to attach event handlers, using AddHandler.

```
Private Enum FormMode
    Adding
    Updating
End Enum

Private _formModeState As FormMode

Private Sub setupForm()

    'test adding
    _formModeState = FormMode.Adding
    setupInput(_formModeState)

    'test updating
    _formModeState = FormMode.Updating
    setupInput(_formModeState)

End Sub

Private Sub setupInput(thisFormMode As FormMode)
    Select Case thisFormMode
        Case FormMode.Adding
            Dim uc As New AddCtrl
            Me.Controls.Add(uc)
        Case FormMode.Updating
            Dim uc As New UpdateCtrl
            Me.Controls.Add(uc)
    End Select
End Sub
```